# This is a TV show going to be a great hit - correct reduced form?

Tags: adjectives, relative-clauses

**Example 1**
‎"This is a TV show that is going to be a great hit."

Is the reduced form of the above sentence like this?

**Example 2**
"This is a TV show going to be a great hit."

Comment: (2) doesn't feel idiomatic to me. It would be simpler to say "This TV show is going to be a great hit".

Answer (score 2):

No.

When forming relative clauses there are tw0 situations.  The first is when the noun modified by the clause is not the subject of the clause.  Then the relativiser "that" is optional.

> an apple that I ate  / an apple I ate

The subject of the verb in the relative clause is "I", and "apple" is the implied object of "ate".

Alternatively, the noun can be the (implied) subject of the clause.  In this case the word "that" cannot be omitted:

> an apple that rolled down the hill

It is incorrect to form "an apple rolled down a hill" with "rolled down a hill" intended as a relative clause.  So "*I ate an apple rolled down a hill" is incorrect.  (*there is a parsing in which "rolled" is the past participle, not past tense, but this is a marked usage in this case)

Similarly in your example the relative clause "is going to be a success" is missing a subject, as it is implied to be the TV show.  So the word "that" is required.